# How to override django admin translated column header (verbose_name of a field)

Tags: model, internationalization, django-admin, field, verbose

I just want to use my own translation for *first name* column header. Just that.

My research leads me to django's own message file containing:

```
#: models.py:235
msgid "first name"
msgstr "nombre propio"
```

So I created the file

> ./site/project/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

and put my new 3 lines

```
#: models.py:235
msgid "first name"
msgstr "nombre"
```

I've tried all possible locations that came to my mind, and in settings:

> LOCALE_PATHS = ('/home/djdev/site/project/locale',)

But alwaws the admin user list shows the default translation for *first name*.

The workaround I've used is create a function and call it in *list_display* as follows:

```
def my_full_name(self, obj):
    try:
        return obj.last_name + ' ' + obj.first_name
    except CustomProfile.DoesNotExist:
        return ''
my_full_name.admin_order_field = 'last_name'

list_display = ('username', 'my_full_name', 'email')
```

... and it is enough for me, but I'm still curious as this is only a workaround for the list view and not for the form.

Regards,

Comment: a. Did you remember to run compilemessages to actually make the django.mo file with the updated translation?
b. Have you tried adding the same "first_name" value in your own locale/es/LAC_MESSAGES/django.po and run compilemessages?

Comment: No... I swore that I've done it (option a) but I forgot it. My bad :( thanks :$

Comment: I'll write that as an answer then :D

Comment: @Martin0x777 did you add those 3 lines manually to the .po file ??

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to always run `python manage.py compilemessages` to actually create the binary `django.mo` file that is needed to display the translated content.